# Is there anyway to track who downloaded a docker image from a private repository

Tags: docker, docker-registry, dockerhub

If I have a private repository is there any possible way I can track who downloaded what versions of the image?

Comment: The registry protocol is “just” HTTP, so this should be technically possible, if you have some way of authenticating callers and have a working implementation of the protocol registry already.  Do you have some proposed changes to the standard registry code you need help with?

Comment: Hadn't looked at an extension yet but will do now! Was wondering if there was something I was overlooking. Thanks for the info!